# unable to get data at other component using navigate in angular 2

Tags: angular

```
**Current Code:**:
```

> Currently i working at filter component. I have data, getting from
>   service and i have successfully navigate to user component.

```
**My Code is**`getFilterDetails(){
this.userService.getFilterDetailsDetails(this.locations).subscribe(data => {
    this.filterType = data;
  });
this.router.navigate(['user']);
}`
*Problem is i need to pass data to user component and how to get data in user component. Kindly help me to get this done?*
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data as:

```
this.router.navigate(['user'], { data: { yourData : yourData } });
```

and retrieve the data

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.route
      .data
      .subscribe(data=> {
        this.data= data || {};
      });
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you please tell me shall i do any changes in below router export const appRoutes : Routes = [

{
  path:'user',
  component: UserComponent
}];

Comment: No need to do any changes. You can dirctly do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared service that you inject in your both component.

```
@Injectable()
export class sharedService {
data: any;
}
```

and in your first component, do something like :

```
this.userService.getFilterDetailsDetails(this.locations).subscribe(data => {
    this.filterType = data;
this.sharedService.data = data;
this.router.navigate(['user']);
  });
}
```

and in the other component, inject the service and use the data.

Comment: i am using like below getFilterDetails(){

this.userService.getFilterDetailsDetails(this.locations).subscribe(data => {
    this.filterType = data;
    this.userService.saveFilterData(this.filterType);

  });

  this.router.navigate(['user']);. but i am getting the error "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'"  and in user component i am using below code to get the data "this.flterData =   this.userService.retrieveFilterData();"

Comment: Are you performing component properties changes in the `AfterViewInit` phase ?

Comment: No. Radouane. shall i include any "ActivatedRoute" or shall i include any module. Kindly help me

Comment: Routing going to usercomponent corrently. but data i am struggle to passing  to user component

Comment: Would you please edit your question and give your all component configuration in it ? Thank you

Comment: I have fixed the above error. now i am not able to get data in user component